# Getting "Parameter undefined" in jQuery with AJAX, MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm building a shopping site in PHP with mysqli database and I have a `"category"` and a `"brands"` sections in that.

What I want is that the user can filter the products in the store by clicking on category & brands section without page refreshing with help of ajax jQuery.

For example on **Category>Electronics** and it will show him the Electronics products on site main page.

Maybe with the code, it will be clearer.

**This is the part of the HTML:**

```
        <div class="panel panel-info">
           <div class="panel-heading">Products</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="getProduct"></div>
            </div>
```

**This is the PHP code in the "action.php" file:**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["getSelectedCategory"])){
        $cid=$_POST["categoryID"];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE productCat = '$cid' ";
        $run_query=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_arry($run_query)){
            $productID = $row["productID"];
            $productCat = $row["productCat"];
            $productBrand = $row["productBrand"];
            $productTitle = $row["productTitle"];
            $productPrice = $row["productPrice"];
            $productIMG = $row["productIMG"];

            echo " <div class='col-md-4'>
 <div class='panel panel-info'>
<div class='panel-heading'>$productTitle</div>
<div class='panel-body'>
 <img src='assets/$productIMG' style='width: 160px; height: 250px;'/>
   </div>
  <div class='panel-heading'>$productPrice.00$
    <button pid='$productID' style='float: right;' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div> ";

 }

}
?>
```

**This is the jQuery code:**

```
   $("body").delegate(".category","click",function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var cid = $(this).attr("categoryID");

        /*Used this alert to see if the
         right category number is shown, Here it says undefined*/
        alert(cid);
       $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {getSelectedCategory: 1, categoryID: cid},
            success: function (data){
                $("#getProduct").html(data);
            }

        })
    });
```

I can't seem to find the problem in my code.

Comment: Where are you storing `categoryID`? Do you not mean `$(this).attr('id');`?

Comment: I'm storing it in my database, in a table called "products".

Comment: Read the second part of my comment.

Comment: when you alert cid, it return correct parameters?

Comment: No. as you can see in   `$cid=$_POST["categoryID"];` it wants 'categoryID'.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani No. its gives "Undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You js code is listening to `.category` class. And there is no such class in your php code template. That's how your `echo` should look like to work:

```
echo " <div class='col-md-4'>
         <div class='panel panel-info'>
           <div class='panel-heading'>$productTitle</div>
             <div class='panel-body'>
               <img src='assets/$productIMG' style='width: 160px; height: 250px;'/>
             </div>
             <div class='panel-heading'>
               <a class='category' categoryID = '$productCat'>$productBrand</a>
                $productPrice.00$
             <button pid='$productID' style='float: right;' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Add To Cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div> ";
```

Look - I've added `<a class="category" categoryID = '$productCat'>$productBrand </a>` to you panel-header.

Comment: It is still undefined.

Comment: You now how to use inspector, right? RightClick on the `<a>` that I added, then look what is the value if categoryID attribute. If there is no value - then you have troubles with DB - some goods are without brands and categories.

Comment: I dont know how to use it. do you mean F12 in chrome?

Comment: yes, web inspector. F12 in chrome or right click and then 'inspect the element'

Comment: you have a mispelling in your while loop - mysqli_fetch_arry should be mysqli_fetch_array()

Comment: also, try just running the php script on its own. so at the top of the script set $_POST["getSelectedCategory"] = 'WHATEVER' and run it to debug and see what you are getting back.